# WARNING: JAXBContext implementation could not be found. WADL feature is disabled

Tags: java, eclipse

> WARNING: JAXBContext implementation could not be found. WADL feature is disabled

How can I resolve this warning?
Is there a way to enable this WADL feature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recomend to you [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632086/java-11-implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-module-path-or-classpa).

I've solved this simply adding [this dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime) in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed the warning (with WADL disabled) in my Jersey Application like this:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put("jersey.config.server.wadl.disableWadl", "true");
setProperties(properties);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43341597/1313699

Comment: The question asks how to turn the feature on, this answers shows how to turn the feature off.